# How to declare and use a dynamic array in xslt in stylesheet 3.0 with xpath https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-array-put

Tags: arrays, xpath, xslt

I have a function as below
'

```
`<xsl:function name="type:iterateICinDef">
    <xsl:param name="pElem" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:param name="parentSpc"/>
    <xsl:param name="sequence" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="cardinality"/>
    <xsl:param name="required"/>
    <xsl:param name="refNameSpc"/>
    <xsl:param name="type"/>
    <xsl:param name="flag" as="xs:integer"/>
    <xsl:param name="hierParent"/>
    <xsl:variable name="refName" select="replace($refNameSpc,'_spc',' ')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="parent" select="replace($parentSpc,'_spc',' ')"/>
    <xsl:if test="not ($pElem/_u0024ref or $pElem/items/_u0024ref)">
        <Repository_spcIC>
            <xsl:attribute name="Name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$refName"></xsl:value-of>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </Repository_spcIC>
    </xsl:if>
   </xsl:function>`
```

In the above the "<xsl:attribute name="Name"> Name should be unique and should not have duplicate for another Repository_spcIC and hence i want to avoid the duplicate by forming a array of names and lookup in the array if the name already exist, if it does exist then i need to put a suffix "__D1" to the name to make the name unique.  If there is repeat of the same name more than twice then the serial no will be incremented to make it unique like "__D2", "__D3" and so on. If the name is unique then i need add that name to the array so that the next call to the function will lookup the array to know if the name already exist to decide to suffix the name or not

This above function are called from another function like below

```
`<xsl:for-each select="/*/definitions/element()">
    <!-- what this loop does is goes one level up, which is definitions
     and then iterate thru all nodes under it i.e each object to match 
    def1 or def2 got earlier-->
        <xsl:if test="name(.)=$def1 or name(.)=$def2">
            <xsl:variable name="cardinality">
                <xsl:if test="required">
                    <xsl:for-each select="required">
                        <countNo>
                            <xsl:if test="(position() &gt; 1)">
                                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </countNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:sequence select="type:iterateICinDef((.),if($flag=1)     
        then $refName else if($pElem/comments) then $pElem/comments
    /text() 
        else $pElem/name(.),$sequence + 1, if($type='array') then 'Zero 
   or More' else 'Zero or One',$cardinality,$referredName, 
   $type,1,$refName)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>`
```

Comment: "then do some action" or "continue loop" sounds like you want to use some imperative/procedural programming approach in XSLT. XSLT rather is declarative programming, XPath uses functions https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#array-functions to work with immutable arrays https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-arrays.

Comment: i see the method
array:append  Returns an array containing all the members of a supplied array, plus one additional member at the end. 
specified in https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-array-append which would update the array right? So i am not getting how you are saying "work with immutable arrays" . Please correct my understanding

Comment: It is a new array that is returned which you can rebind to the same variable if you want, but the original array is not changed. So in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93nwMnQ with `<xsl:variable name="a1" select="['a', 'b']"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="a2" select="array:append($a1, 'c')"/>` the result of `array:size($a1), array:size($a2)` is `2 3`, meaning the original array is not changed, rather a new array with one item more is created.

Comment: And you can pretty much do the same with sequences e.g. `<xsl:variable name="a1" select="'a', 'b'"/>` and `<xsl:variable name="a2" select="$a1, 'c'"/>` and `count($a1), count($a2)` gives `2 3`. So as others have pointed out in comments to your previous questions and here in comments and answers, I think you need to better show us the input you want to process and the output you want to create. Then we might be able to tell how to use XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays, like everything else in the XDM data model, are immutable. This means that you can never change an existing array "in situ", you can only create a new array by making changes to an existing array.

You've expressed your needs in terms of procedural pseudo-code, and XSLT isn't a procedural language, so it's quite hard to reverse engineer your code to work out what the real requirement is. It's much better to explain your requirements by describing the input and the output of the process, rather than as a sequence of actions to get from one to the other.

The very phrase "one at a time" in your question rings alarm bells. In a declarative, functional language like XSLT there is no notion of time, no concept of things happening one after the other.

It's also not clear that you need XDM arrays here. I suspect that XDM sequences are going to be easier to work with. Arrays are a 3.0 bolt-on to the language (introduced primarily to support JSON), while sequences have been there since 2.0 and are much more deeply integrated into the processing model. For example, XSLT's `xsl:for-each` instruction can be used to process each individual item in a sequence, but there is no equivalent instruction to process each member of an array.

I could explain the detailed syntax for setting up a sequence or array that's empty, or one that contains a collection of strings, but I'm not at all sure this would be helpful. It would be much better if you could explain your requirements in functional terms (what's the input, what's the output, and how do they relate?), and that will probably be much easier to translate into XSLT code.

**== UPDATE ==**

In your update to the question, you've explained that you want to write a function that generates unique values. To achieve this, you're proposing that the function has a memory of previous calls so that it can avoid generating the same value twice. So the function needs to modify something external (specifically, its memory of previous calls): it is a function with side effects, often called an "impure function", and this is strongly discouraged, or impossible, in pure functional programming languages.

There are various workarounds to this problem, of which the most common are perhaps:

- Generate a value that's a function of the thing you are currently processing in the input, for example by using `position()` or `generate-id()` or `xsl:number`.
- Generate a value that's effectively random and that has an extremely low probability of repeating (for example, something based on a current timestamp). That's how UUIDs generally work; a value that is only likely to come up once every million years is unique enough for most practical purposes.
- Write a function that delivers a generator, where a generator has two properties: a value that you can use this time, and a new generator that you can call to get further values. That's the way the built-in function `fn:random-number-generator()` works. This is the way functional programming enthusiasts would do it, but it takes a bit of getting used to if you're new to functional programming.

Comment: My requirement is to use the array for string comparision to see whether a string  say 'xyz' already exist or not in the array and if exist then do some action (out side of the array but not processing of the array elements itself) else append the compared string ('xyz') to the array

Comment: Using an array is not your requirement, it is your proposed solution to the requirement. Tell us what you want to achieve, not how you want to go about achieving it.

Comment: I did not mean "write a function". What i want is the value of the "Name" attribute produced by "$refName" from the first call (lets say there are 3 calls in total) to the function "iterateICinDef" should be unique (my requirement) compared to next two calls. If there is a repetition then i would make it unique by adding a suffix  "__D1" to the value got from "$refName".  
To achieve this i should be able to store and retrieve the values of "$refName" got from previous calls to function "iterateICinDef"
e.g 1st call i got "xy", 2nd call if i get again 'xy' then make it 'xy__D1'

Comment: I am not proposing now (earlier i did proposing by using arrays).  I am asking how to achieve it such that to hold in memory between calls so that if i get the same value then i can make it unique by appending "__D1" to the value got from "$refName"

Comment: You're still using verbs like "store" and "retrieve" and "hold in memory", which are imperative procedural actions with side-effects. You haven't grasped that functional programming is different.

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique names as you described you could recalculate the names in a previous step. The code shows how this could be accomplished:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> 

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> 

    <xsl:variable name="data">
        <data>
            <item name="A"/>
            <item name="A"/>
            <item name="B"/>
            <item name="A"/>
            <item name="C"/>
            <item name="C1"/>
            <item name="C1"/>
            <item name="C11"/>
            <item name="C1"/>
            <item name="C11"/>
            <item name="C12"/>
            <item name="D"/>
            <item name="A"/>
        </data>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template name="makeunique">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:if test="not($data/data/item[@replaced = 'true']) and $data/data/item/@replaced">
            <data>
                <xsl:for-each select="$data/data/item">
                    <item name="{@name}" origname="{@origname}"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </data>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="$data/data/item[@replaced = 'true'] or not($data/data/item/@replaced)">
            <xsl:variable name="newData">
                <data>
                    <xsl:for-each select="$data/data/item">
                        <xsl:variable name="name">
                            <xsl:if test="./preceding-sibling::item[@name = current()/@name]">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(current()/@name,./preceding-sibling::item[@name = current()/@name]/last()+1)"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="not(./preceding-sibling::item[@name = current()/@name]) and not(./following-sibling::item[@name = current()/@name])">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="not(./preceding-sibling::item[@name = current()/@name]) and (./following-sibling::item[@name = current()/@name])">
                                <xsl:value-of select="concat(current()/@name,'1')"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <xsl:variable name="origname">
                            <xsl:if test="not(current()/@origname)">
                                <xsl:value-of select="current()/@name"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:if test="current()/@origname">
                                <xsl:value-of select="current()/@origname"/>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <item name="{$name}" origname="{$origname}" replaced="{not($name = current()/@name)}"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </data>
            </xsl:variable>   
            <xsl:call-template name ="makeunique">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$newData"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>     

    <xsl:template name="test"> 
        <xsl:call-template name ="makeunique">
            <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$data"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template> 
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <item name="A1" origname="A"/>
   <item name="A2" origname="A"/>
   <item name="B" origname="B"/>
   <item name="A3" origname="A"/>
   <item name="C" origname="C"/>
   <item name="C11" origname="C1"/>
   <item name="C121" origname="C1"/>
   <item name="C111" origname="C11"/>
   <item name="C13" origname="C1"/>
   <item name="C112" origname="C11"/>
   <item name="C122" origname="C12"/>
   <item name="D" origname="D"/>
   <item name="A4" origname="A"/>
</data>
```

*BTW: This solution is more for XSLT enthusiasts. I would prefer using a function with side effects here.*

Comment: your attempt to resolve my problem is great, with a good example, but in my case the $data you declared is not known before hand.  it comes from another xml which is the input on top of which the xslt is being applied to get the required output.  So, in the output there is a constraint that it need to have unique values for Names and hence is the problem statement.